# GitHub Basis Data Export: SSL certificate

Tags: php, ssl, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to access data from my Basis fitness watch by using these instructions from GitHub (https://github.com/btroia/basis-data-export).

I am having problems with the SSL certificate. I saved the file to c:\wamp\cacert.pem as it says, and then "update php.ini ...". However, I get the error, "'update' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". Please help! I am new at programming, and this is a big challenge for me.

How do you add a SSL certificate? Thank you!!